# How to observe multiple properties with Delegatecommand.ObservesProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I would like to observe multiple properties in my viewmodel to check the CanExecute Method.

**Question:**

How to register more properties?

**Example:**

```
class MyViewModel
        {
            public int myproperty1 { get; set; }
            public int myproperty2 { get; set; }

            public DelegateCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

            public MyViewModel()
            {
                MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandMethod,CanExecuteMyCommandMethod);
                MyCommand.ObservesProperty((() => myproperty1));
                // line below doesnt work Exeception "Value is already observed". How to register more properties to observe?
                MyCommand.ObservesProperty((() => myproperty2));

            }

            private bool CanExecuteMyCommandMethod()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            private void MyCommandMethod()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

PropertChanged event is done by Propertchanged.Fody INPC.

ObservesProperty is to RaiseCanExecuteChanged. 
The second property observe registration raise a exception "Value is already observed).

**Additional Question:**
ObservesProperty((() => myproperty;

Allows multiple or single property?
If somebody else confirm multiple registration shall be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `ObservesProperty` method for another property like you are doing should work. But you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setters of the source properties for the `CanExecuteChanged` event to be raised.

Please refer to the following sample code.

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _myproperty1;
    public int myproperty1
    {
        get { return _myproperty1; }
        set { _myproperty1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int _myproperty2;
    public int myproperty2
    {
        get { return _myproperty2; }
        set { _myproperty2 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandMethod, CanExecuteMyCommandMethod);
        MyCommand.ObservesProperty((() => myproperty1));
        MyCommand.ObservesProperty((() => myproperty2));
    }

    private bool CanExecuteMyCommandMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void MyCommandMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ObservesProperty is to RaiseCanExecuteChanged. The INotifiyPropertyChanged is done by Propertychanged.Fody INPC. The second property observe registration raise a exception "Value is already observed).

Comment: Ok, then I have to figure out, who made already the registration, maybe a smart 3rd party framework control element.

Comment: Marked as answered

Comment: Inside `public MyViewModel()` it should be `MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandMethod, CanExecuteMyCommandMethod).ObservesProperty((() => myproperty1)).ObservesProperty((() => myproperty2));`